# Solvability condition for special matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have a matrix A where row 3 = row 1 + row 2, what solvability conditions does this impose on b for Ax = b?

Part of me thinking that it means that b3 = b2 + b1, but I also feel like since the column space is different than the row space, b just has to be a linear combination of the columns of A?

Comment: Try some numerical  examples, e.g. 1column three rows, ..., 3 columns three rows

Comment: @SomeOne yeah tried this with a few examples. Seems to only work when b3 = b1 + b2.